# Should I use a reference?

Tags: c++, performance, micro-optimization

I have a class containing an implementation pointer. Therefore, in some functions, I refer to a member of the implementation several times. Is it a good idea to write

```
// approach 1
std::string & str = m_pImpl->m_str;
str.clear();
str += "blablabla";
// ...
return str.c_str();
```

once and use the reference to save the pointer indirection, or should I save the reference variable (This is always 4 or 8 bytes, like a pointer, right?)?

```
// approach 2
m_pImpl->m_str.clear();
m_pImpl->m_str += "blablabla";
// ...
return m_pImpl->m_str.c_str();
```

In my usecase the variable m_pImpl->m_str is used about 10 to 20 times. I am afraid I can hardly profile the performance difference between these two approaches. Does anybody know or can anybody test it makes a difference? Does this depend on how often I use the variable (one time versus 20 times versus 10000 times)? Or does a decent compiler do the same thing as approach 1 anyway?

Comment: ... Or use the latter and leave the rest to compiler. I would be surprised if those approaches would compile into different code. Use whatever you find more readable.

Comment: approach 3: `return m_pImpl->GetBlablabla();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to do the job of a modern compiler as they place a lot of emphasis on code optimisation: shy away from purported improvement tricks such as these.

Not only is it obfuscating but approach 1 is also vulnerable to an errant refactorer dropping the `&` in the definition of `str`: if that is ever done then the returned pointer will be *dangling* and the program behaviour *undefined*! It's for these reasons that I would disallow approach 1 in my codebase.

Answer (score 3):

From 8.3.2 References §4

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage

So I would suggest use the code that looks more readable to you and leave the rest to the compiler.